# passing multiple bash variables so they are next to each other in a sed command

Tags: linux, bash, loops, variables, sed

I am trying to cycle through two files so that each combination of values is searched for in a third file. Where file 1 is the name of duplicate strings that appear in file 3:

```
m54118_131101_153642/10223738/ccs
m54118_131101_153642/10682485/ccs
m54118_131101_153642/10748114/ccs
```

and file 2 is a list of different condition identifiers:

```
Ident_1
Ident_2
Condition1
Condition2
```

file 3 contains the duplicates and the rest of the data:

```
m54118_191101_153642/10223738/ccs Ident_1
m54118_191101_153642/10223738/ccs Condition2
m54118_191101_153642/10682485/ccs Ident_1
m54118_191101_153642/10748114/ccs Ident_2
```

I want to change $2 of identical $1 duplicates to a generic string so that all identical $1's can be collapsed later whilst the rest of the data is still present.

So far I am trying to do it with sed and two 'while read' loops but I need the variable from each file next to each other separated by a tab:

```
{ while read line ; do
        name1=`echo ${line}`

                {
                while read anotherline ; do
                name2=`echo ${anotherline}`
                #remove the slashes so they don't interfere with sed
                sed 's,/,-,g' file3 | sed 's/'"$name1"'\t'"$name2"'/'"$name1"'\tMultipleName2s/g' >> found_duplicates

                done } < file2

done } < file1
```

But I keep getting the following errors:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 33: unknown option to `s'
sed: -e expression #1, char 33: unknown option to `s'
sed: -e expression #1, char 33: unknown option to `s'
sed: -e expression #1, char 33: unknown option to `s'
sed: -e expression #1, char 33: unknown option to `s'
sed: -e expression #1, char 33: unknown option to `s'
sed: -e expression #1, char 33: unknown option to `s'
sed: -e expression #1, char 33: unknown option to `s'
sed: -e expression #1, char 33: unknown option to `s'
sed: -e expression #1, char 33: unknown option to `s'
sed: -e expression #1, char 33: unknown option to `s'
sed: -e expression #1, char 33: unknown option to `s'
sed: -e expression #1, char 33: unknown option to `s'
```

I am pretty new at sed so any help would be much appreciated! I have gone through alot of other articles but they relate to a single bash variable being passed into sed and I just cannot seem to get it too work.

EDIT:
Expected outcome as compared to the file 3 box above would be:

```
m54118_191101_153642/10223738/ccs Multiple_Names
m54118_191101_153642/10223738/ccs Multiple_Names
m54118_191101_153642/10682485/ccs Ident_1
m54118_191101_153642/10748114/ccs Ident_2
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, special thanks for showing us your efforts in code writing. It is advisable on SO to show us expected sample output too, so could you please do add the same in your question and let us know then.

Comment: `name1=$(echo "$line")` is essentially the same as `name1=$line`; you can just use `line` in place of `name1`, or write `read name1`.

Comment: Any time you're thinking about file data in the terms of numbered fields, ie. `$1`, `$2`, `...`. you'll find your task much easier to solve using a langage that is designed with numbered columns in mind, i.e. `awk`. Check out [Awk Tutorial](http://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) . `Sed` is really not the tool you want to use for this process (IHML). Good luck!

Comment: The slashes in `name1` are interfering with the `sed` command. It looks like you're trying to fix this by removing slashes from the file, but that doesn't fix the ones in the variable. You'd be better off using a different delimiter (one that'll never appear in a variable). Also, I think the logic is off; this doesn't search for duplicates, it just looks for all entries. It also adds all entries to found_duplicates whether or not they match the search/replace pattern, it just only does the replacement on matching lines.